# VC++ app fails to start — but there's no error

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, startup

I made a minor change to a legacy Visual C++ / MFC app built with VS 2008. I changed some UI resources in the `.rc` file and compiled without any problems, then deployed it on my client's system. However, the program which was previously doing fine now fails to run on exactly one of their servers. It works fine on my laptop and on their other servers, many of whom are basically identical to the one having the trouble.

The weird thing however is that there is absolutely no error message whatsoever. No message box, no [errorlevel](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/if.mspx?mfr=true) set (when run on command prompt), no Dr. Watson entry, no nothing.

It's an MFC app that does not really comprise anything very special. It does link in some external libraries – e.g., some old version of the [Xerces C++ XML parser](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/). But this is probably not too relevant, right?

The program has a class derived from [CWinApp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362kaah4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), and I tried to add some logging in its constructor. Based on this, it looks like not even this constructor is reached.

The server in question is running Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition Service Pack 2, and we are trying to run the program in a Remote Desktop session. (Because of the client's environment, I cannot easily test in a console session right now.)

I reverted my changes from version control, which did not help – but I do not know if I had built myself the previously installed version (which ran just fine even on this server) or if it had been built by someone else.

Have also tried to reinstall the Visual C++ runtime libraries and of course reboot Windows, but neither helped. Now I'm really running out of ideas... Any clues on what I could try or check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably some error occurs but is surpressed e.g. empty catch() statement or similar.

You could try and install Debugging tools for Windows [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463016) to see if you could get more info when trying to run it. Since the download is rather small 25Mb maybe it is possible to install it on your client's PC.

But first check the eventview log for your app, maybe there is something in there that can shed some light.

Comment: Yep – looking at Event Viewer did help indeed. Not the Application section though, but System. There was a message informing me that the server in question did not have the correct versions of all the Boost DLLs employed. Surely missing DLLs had been pretty much the first thing I was thinking of, but I also figured that Windows should've shown a message box if that had been the problem. Oh my.